# What is the difference between Override and hiding static method of superclass

Tags: java

If a subclass implements a instance method which has the same signature with its superclass, it is called override.

Comparatively if "override" a static method of its superclass, it is called hiding.

What is the difference between these two concepts in memory during function call ?

Comment: What do you mean "in memory"?

Comment: There's nothing being hidden when creating a static method with the same name. Static methods are always invoked on the class; no inheritance or hiding is possible.

Comment: @MarounMaroun  for instance, what would be the difference when both these concepts are mapped into bytecode (.class)

Comment: @TomG I just follow the terms used by java official tutorial  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: The explanations in the referenced tutorial are quite clear, aren't they? What isn't clear?

Comment: @Hellolad I guess that the bytecode would be very different between the two cases: when you override a method, the invocation of that method is referred to a particular object of that class; when you invoke a static method, the call is associated directly to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addresses of static methods are determined at *compile time*. So there is no need to search further for the method address, it's decided way before.

*Overridden* method addresses are determined at *run time*. It depends on the instance and the address of the method is searched from base method to overridden method.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding is a run-time phenomenon which depends on object and objects are created at run time so function call will be decided based on object at run time.

Whereas Static method calling is done by adding a class name like

```
           MyClass.abc();
```

This does not depends on object as you are clearly mentioning the class name at compile time which has nothing to do with object because this static method is global to all object. So whatever class name you will mention that method will be called in case of the static method.